# Enable cascade on delete in entity framework, with dotconnect

Tags: entity-framework, postgresql, devart, dotconnect

I am trying to enable cascade on delete in entity framework, using postgresql and the dotconnect database connector.
According to [this](http://blogs.devart.com/dotconnect/entity-framework-tips-and-tricks-part-3.html#third) guide I'm supposed to edit the CSDL and SSDL that I should be able to find in "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Xml\Schemas" according to [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb399604%28v=vs.100%29.aspx). I did find the CSDL  and SSDL files, but when I opened them they did not contain any line (or anything remotely similar to) .
The blog is 3 years old so the information is probably outdated, but where do I go from here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please open your model in Entity Developer ( http://www.devart.com/entitydeveloper/ed-vs-edm.html ), navigate to Model Explorer > ModelName.Store > Constraints > open Storage Constrain Editor for your constraint and set the "Delete Action" property to Cascade.

Comment: Thanks a bunch. This is, of course, exactly what I was looking for.
(Didn't even know I had entity developer, just used the postgresql database connector so far)